# while using pool.starmap code is not running as multiprocess

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am running following code:

```
import os
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool

def clean_directories_mp(periodDays, dirs):
    chunks = [dirs[i::4] for i in range(4)]
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    tup = [(chunks, periodDays)]
    pool.starmap(clean_directories, tup)
    return 0

def clean_directories(dirs, periodDays):
    print (dirs)
    print (periodDays)
    print (os.getpid())
    for directory in dirs:
        print (directory)
    return 0

dirs = get_directories(cleanupPath)
clean_directories_mp(periodDays, dirs)
```

And ufortunately it runs as single process.
If I use just pool.map instead of pool.starmap it works okay:

```
def clean_directories_mp(periodDays, dirs):
    chunks = [dirs[i::4] for i in range(4)]
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(clean_directories, chunks)
    return 0

def clean_directories(dirs, periodDays):
    print (dirs)
    print (periodDays)
    print (os.getpid())
    for directory in dirs:
        print (directory)
    return 0

dirs = get_directories(cleanupPath)
clean_directories_mp(periodDays, dirs)
```

I want to pass 2 arguments to clean_directories function (chunk of the list of dirs and periodDays)
How do I do it correctly with pool.starmap?

Answer (score 0):

```
chunks = [dirs[i::4] for i in range(4)]
```

chunks is a list

it looks like for:
pool.map you can pass a 'chunks' list and it is automatically iterated for each process:

```
pool.map(clean_directories, chunks)
```

and for pool.starmap, you need to pass explicit tuples, because chunks list won't be automatically iterated:

```
for c in range(len(chunks)):
    arguments.append((chunks[c], periodDays))
```